# For loop does not execute the first command after 2nd time

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankAccount1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    char pickup;
    char size;
    char type;
    String name;

    double cost=0.0;
    int i;


    for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("size of pizza: ");
    size =  input.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.println("type of pizza: ");
    type = input.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.println("pick up or delivery?");
    pickup = input.next().charAt(0);


    if(size == 'S' || type == 'V') {cost = 10.0;}
    else if(size == 'M' || type == 'V') {cost = 12.25;}
    else if(size == 'L' || type == 'V') {cost = 14.50;}
    else if(size == 'S' || type == 'C') {cost = 7.0;}
    else if(size == 'M' || type == 'C') {cost = 8.0;}
    else if(size == 'L' || type == 'C') {cost = 9.0;}


    if(pickup == 'D'){
    cost=cost+1.50;
    System.out.println("Name: "+name+". Your cost is: "+cost);}
    else { 
    System.out.println("Name: "+name+". Your cost is: "+cost);}


    } 

}

}
```

I have a for loop in my code, and it asks the name, size, type and pickup. The first time it is run, it asks all fields to be entered, but for the 2nd time, the name field does not let me input the name for some reason, it prints the "What is your name?" but it does not let me enter the name...? can someone tell me why?
Thanks.

this is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb1BA.jpg

Comment: What is different about each of the input.* calls? One of them is not like the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the fact that

```
input.next()
```

does not consume newline characters, these get passed passed back to your loop and does not allow a value to be entered. You would need to add:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   // existing input.next() statements in here
  ...

   input.nextLine();
}
```

at the end of the `for` loop to fix.

Comment: I tested it with the inputs in the image and didnt get any exception. `Scanner.next` will trim leading spaces automatically.

Answer (score 3):

When you use a `Scanner` with `System.in`, data isn't read from `System.in` until a newline (you've hit **Enter**). So what you actually have in the Scanner's buffer is:

```
Jake\nL\nV\nD\n
```

The key here is that `D` doesn't get sent to the Scanner's buffer until you've pressed enter. That's why there's that `\n` at the end. Normally, when you're calling `input.next()`, that previous stray newline gets gobbled up. But when you call `input.nextLine()` the second/third time around the for loop, it's reading that stray trailing newline:

```
    here ----v
Jake\nL\nV\nD\n
```

So you get a blank line, essentially reading everything between the `D` and `\n`, which is nothing.

You need to call `nextLine()` each time and call `charAt(0)` on the resulting String.

Comment: do i need to change the pickup to String type too?

Comment: @kevinQu No, `input.nextLine().charAt(0)` is all you need to do

Answer (score 2):

Replace your input.next()'s with input.nextLine()'s. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and this helped me.
declare this outside the loop:

```
boolean ranOnce=false;
```

then inside the loop declare this

```
if(!ranOnce){ranOnce=true;String s=input.nextLine();}
```